# Get all CONVERT(datetime) styles (formats)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date-format

I know this is kinda stupid to ask but is there a Transact-SQL function or anything that returns all `CONVERT(datetime)` styles (formats)? Something like `fnDateFormats` will return all date formats:

Output:

```
Dateformat | SQL code
MM/DD/YYYY | 101
```

and so on.

Answer (score 11):

There is no such built-in function – or system table, or view – that would give you a list of all styles (formats). Otherwise people would not have been creating custom-made style lists (like [this one](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx), for instance) – as a way of a reminder, I guess, because the same information can be found in the [online documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql), even if slightly differently arranged.

Go ahead and create one for yourself. New styles are sometimes introduced with new major releases, but those do not happen too often, so maintaining such a list should not be much of a burden.

Another thing is whether you really need to have such a table. Unless you are still using a pre-2012 version, you can format your datetime values arbitrarily with the [FORMAT() function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql).

Answer (score 2):

Even though there is no built-in function to do this in SQL Server, there is nothing preventing you from writing your own function, outputting something like this:

```
OriginalValue                   Style   ConvertedValue

2017-12-31 23:59:29.123456789   1       12/31/17
2017-12-31 23:59:29.123456789   2       17.12.31
2017-12-31 23:59:29.123456789   3       31/12/17
2017-12-31 23:59:29.123456789   4       31.12.17
2017-12-31 23:59:29.123456789   5       31-12-17
2017-12-31 23:59:29.123456789   6       31 Dec 17
2017-12-31 23:59:29.123456789   7       Dec 31, 17
2017-12-31 23:59:29.123456789   8       23:59:29
2017-12-31 23:59:29.123456789   9       Dec 31 2017 11:59:29.1234568PM
2017-12-31 23:59:29.123456789   10      12-31-17
...
```

Here is my code for this, it displays attempts at converting a `DateTime2(7)` field to a `NVarChar` for Styles 1 up to 150.

```
DECLARE
     @OriginalDate datetime2 = N'2017-12-31 23:59:29.123456789'
    ,@Try_Top_X_Styles smallint = 150
    ,@ConvertFromType nvarchar(50) = 'DATETIME2(7)'
    ,@ConvertToType nvarchar(50) = 'NVARCHAR(500)';


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.##DateFormats') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE ##DateFormats;

SELECT @OriginalDate AS OriginalDate
    ,CONVERT(BIGINT,0) AS Style
    ,CONVERT(NVARCHAR(500),@OriginalDate,120) AS ConvertedDate
INTO ##DateFormats
WHERE 0 = 1;

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT
    TOP (@Try_Top_X_Styles)
    @sql = @sql + N'BEGIN TRY
INSERT INTO ##DateFormats
SELECT N''' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50),@OriginalDate,127) + N'''
,CONVERT(BIGINT,' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20),ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))) + N')
,CONVERT(' + @ConvertToType + ',CONVERT(' + @ConvertFromType + ',''' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50),@OriginalDate,127) + N'''),' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20),ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))) + N');
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    INSERT INTO ##DateFormats
    SELECT N''' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50),@OriginalDate,127) + N'''
    ,CONVERT(BIGINT,' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20),ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))) + N')
    ,ERROR_MESSAGE()
END CATCH
'
FROM sys.columns;

--PRINT (@sql); --For The Debug!
EXEC (@sql);
GO
SELECT *
FROM ##DateFormats
WHERE ConvertedDate NOT LIKE '%not a valid style number%'
ORDER BY Style;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the fun of it...

```
DECLARE @n INT = 0, @v nvarchar(100);
WHILE @n < 10000
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY 
        SELECT @v = CONCAT(@n, N'       ', CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), GETDATE(), @n));
        RAISERROR(@v, 0, 1);
        SET @n += 1;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SET @n += 1;
    END CATCH;
END;
```

Output...

```
0       May  2 2019  1:42PM
1       05/02/19
2       19.05.02
3       02/05/19
4       02.05.19
5       02-05-19
6       02 May 19
7       May 02, 19
8       13:42:19
9       May  2 2019  1:42:19:633PM
10      05-02-19
11      19/05/02
12      190502
13      02 May 2019 13:42:19:633
14      13:42:19:633
20      2019-05-02 13:42:19
21      2019-05-02 13:42:19.633
22      05/02/19  1:42:19 PM
23      2019-05-02
24      13:42:19
25      2019-05-02 13:42:19.633
100     May  2 2019  1:42PM
101     05/02/2019
102     2019.05.02
103     02/05/2019
104     02.05.2019
105     02-05-2019
106     02 May 2019
107     May 02, 2019
108     13:42:19
109     May  2 2019  1:42:19:633PM
110     05-02-2019
111     2019/05/02
112     20190502
113     02 May 2019 13:42:19:633
114     13:42:19:633
120     2019-05-02 13:42:19
121     2019-05-02 13:42:19.633
126     2019-05-02T13:42:19.633
127     2019-05-02T13:42:19.633
130     27 شعبان 1440  1:42:19:633PM
131     27/08/1440  1:42:19:633PM
```